# Unable to delete created and streamed file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, imagemagick

I'm using [Magick.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-x86/) to convert a PDF to a PNG and stream it back to the page via ajax.

Everything works until a PDF is uploaded twice. When trying to overwrite or delete the existing file, the debugger tells me that the file is in use by another process.

Here's my function that returns an Image to the controller:

```
    //path is a fully qualified path to a file ending in .PDF
    private Image ConvertPDFTOneImage(string path)
    {
        MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
        settings.Density = new PointD(300, 300);

        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
            images.Read(file);
            file = null;

            using (MagickImage horizontal = images.AppendHorizontally())
            {
                string PNGName = Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".png");
                horizontal.Write(PNGName);
            }

            return Image.FromFile(path.Replace("pdf", "png"));
        }
    }
```

And my controller that streams the response back to the browser:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData([FromUri] int sellerID, [FromUri] int eventID, [FromUri] string section, [FromUri] string row, [FromUri] string seat)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
            {
                try
                {
                    string base64 = string.Empty;
                    SellerObjects.Externeal.SellerTicket TicketToSave = new SellerObjects.Externeal.SellerTicket();

                    TicketToSave.UploadedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
                    SellerTicketRepo TheLocalSellerRepo = new SellerTicketRepo(TicketToSave);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        TheLocalSellerRepo.GetConvertedPDFImage().Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    }

                    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    result.Content = new StringContent(base64);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error saving file.");
                }
            }

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "An error has occurred");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the Image class that you are returning is a System.Drawing.Image. You need to Dispose this object to release the file lock.

```
// Instead of this:
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  TheLocalSellerRepo.GetConvertedPDFImage().Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

// Should you be doing this:
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (Image img = TheLocalSellerRepo.GetConvertedPDFImage())
  {
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
  }
}

// Or you could even do this (if GetConvertedPDFImage() returns a MagickImage):
using (MagickImage img = TheLocalSellerRepo.GetConvertedPDFImage())
{
  img.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
  base64 = img.ToBase64();
}
```

Comment: Ah, awesome catch. Thank you! I didn't know the image needed to be disposed